# How to send apostrophe (') in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm stuck to hold a specific character. The code does work with letters but doesn't work with apostrophe.

```
'::
{
pressed:=!pressed
if(pressed)
{
    sendinput,{' down}
}
else
{
    sendinput,{' up}
}
}
return
```

Does anyone have idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might happen because you send apostrophe and you use apostrophe as the hotkey.
Here is special syntax to avoid the recursive Send command:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar

So you can use the same key but then need to prefix the hotkey with dollar sign $.

This will work:

```
$'::
    send {' down}
    send {' up}
return
```

But this will not work:

```
'::
    send {' down}
    send {' up}
return
```

Comment: This solved my problem. TY!

Comment: It does not work for me.